# Can I add a WatchKit Extension to a Universal app?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have an app in the App Store. It is for iPhone and iPad (Universal). Can I add a WatchKit Extension in the next version or do I have to remove iPad from the targets in order to do that? I'm asking because iPad does not support connecting an Apple Watch.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** you can add a WatchKit extension to a universal app. As a general rule, if you add an extension to an app that a device cannot support, it simply won't appear there.

Answer (score 1):

In your existing App in Xcode in the `Editor` menu select `Add Target...`

[image]

from there select `watchOS` and `WatchKit App`.

[image]

Name the WatchKit Extension, and you should be all set.